# database not inserting values in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Below is a piece of code from my Register Controller. As you can see, every field has a value, but its not inserting into database. I have configured default values to these fields in database, if values are not present. It gives row don't have default value. I am unable to figure out the problem. I also have all fields fillable in Models.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  $user = Account::create([
    'wallet' => $data['wallet'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'balance' => 0,
    'uqid' => rand(10000000,99999999) ,
    'ref' => 0,

  ]);
$gnl = General::first();
$track = Track::create([
    'account_id' => $user->id,
    'speed' => $gnl->dhs_free,
    'balance' => 0,
    'uqid' => rand(10000000,99999999) ,
    'ref' => 0,

  ]);
```

**Account Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['wallet','uqid','ref','bstatus','refcom','email','verified'];

   public function deposit()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Deposit','id','account_id');
   }
   public function withdraw()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Withdraw','id','account_id');
   }
   public function track()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Track','id','account_id');
   }
```

**Track Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Track extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array( 'account_id','speed','withdraw','status');

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check the log file if there is an explanation ?  (storage/logs/laravel.log)

Comment: no error in it i have checked many times

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: 1. error following colmn do not have default value.  2. if i add default value to colmn then it  insert only default value not from controller

Comment: please post your models in your question too

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din check now

Comment: @ceejayoz sir any idea?

Comment: i think the problem is with the Account::create ( ) , your "balance" field is not added on the fillable array, and ido you give defaultValues for your "bstatus" , "refcom" and "verified" fields ?

Comment: your Track::create( ) also ahs problems, there is no balance field on your fillable field.

Comment: yes these have default values

Comment: try to check you fillable arrays along with your create ( ) methods okey ?

Comment: @WaqarAli The **exact** error message, please. I know the error message wasn't "error following colmn do not have default value". Please give us the full message.

Answer (score 0):

When using the create function, it seems you are not filling all the fields in the table.

Either, ensure you're assigning values to all fields in the create() function, or ensure there are default values in the database. In the builder, use ->default(0) or something.

Comment: as you can see i am assigning to each field but its not inserting

Comment: The default value error means that you are trying to create a row where a field hasn't been assigned a value, or given a default value. Check everything over carefully and you will find your mistake

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which can be identified in your code :

Firstly the number and name of the columns in the Model and create method are different :

`Account` Model contains :

```
protected $fillable = ['wallet','uqid','ref','bstatus','refcom','email','verified'];
```

But your create contains :

```
'wallet' => $data['wallet'],
'email' => $data['email'],
'balance' => 0,
'uqid' => rand(10000000,99999999) ,
'ref' => 0,
```

Create does not contain bstatus, refcom and so on... columns but those are present in your Model and in the database table.

Similarly, `Track` Model contains :

```
 protected $fillable = ['account_id','speed','withdraw','status'];
```

But its create contains :

```
'account_id' => $user->id,
'speed' => $gnl->dhs_free,
'balance' => 0,
'uqid' => rand(10000000,99999999) ,
'ref' => 0,
```

Now, if your non-specified columns in `create()` function do not have any default value specified in database, you will get  :

> Error : row don't have default value

Solution either add values to those columns in `create()` or mark those columns are `nullable` using a migration.

Comment: thanks but those have default values at registration and have seprate code to update them

Comment: Yes, but when you are doing `create()` it is inserting a new record for the first time. So independent of the any other code, it will still error out in here :)